# Skip template parameters

Tags: c++

How come that I'm allowed to skip template parameters(see comments)? And why am I getting a linking error?

```
template <typename T>
class Number {
public:
    Number(int val) {}

    // Why can I skip template arguments here?
    friend Number operator* (Number first, Number second);
};

template<typename T>
Number<T> operator* (Number<T> lhs, Number<T> rhs) {
    return Number<T>(42);
}

int main() {
    Number<int> num1(22), num2(23);
    Number<int> res = num1 * num2;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't 4th line be Number(T val) {} ?

Comment: Your friend function declaration is wrong: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends

Comment: The same as you don't need it for your constructor, it is implicit as member/friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The template arguments of a class template can be omitted only if its name appears within the scope of that class. So your `friend` declaration implicitly takes two `Number<T>` parameters, but note that it is **not** a template.
2. Because it is not a template, the `T` in the two `Number<T>` parameters are actually `int` as you've specified in the instantiation of `num1` and `num2`. Therefore your `friend` declaration is actually:

   ```
   friend Number operator* (Number<int> first, Number<int> second);
   ```
3. The definition of your function template below `Number` is a separate overload than the one you declared as a friend. This is because the first one is a regular function that takes two `Number<int>` while the second is a function template that can be instantiated with any `Number<T>` instances. Since it is a separate overload, it is **not** a friend of `Number` and as such cannot access private/protected members of `Number`.
4. `num1 * num2` chooses to call your regular friend function since both parameters match exactly. Since that function hasn't been defined you receive an undefined reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're in the scope of the templated class.

The class instantiates with the type argument, and in within that scope the name `Number` is actually `Number<T>` with the assigner type T.

Notice that also the constructor doesn't need the template argument.

The friend operator for Number would instantiate to:

```
 friend Number<int> operator* (Number<int> first, Number<int> second);
```